# Maven optionally compile dependency from svn repository

Tags: maven-2

Is there way to optionally compile dependency from source (svn) instead of using the remote jar?

Background:
I have a very very large j2ee project and we do not want the developer to have to download the entire project on to there system. Specially under a IDE where 20+ project can cause performance problem when compiling... debugging... eclipse crash causing weird phantom dependency problem... etc.

So we are setting up maven to download all dependency from a private repository, which works great. But I still want to be able to work on the dependency that it is downloading.

my solution:
My solution to this at the moment is the following...

1. download module I want to work on from svn
2. work on code
3. mvn install to local repository
4. create ear package
5. deploy and test

problems with my solution:

If I'm done with the development of the specific module, I am not sure how to tell maven to start downloading from remote repository again. Do I just uninstall and let it download next time it need to sync up?

Is there other solution to this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: It looks like the case using a multimodule build first and second change the organization of the project. Are the modules related to the J2EE project (i assume yes)...BTW: What does "large" mean ?

Comment: Depends on the module. Like our bean is being used across multiple war but gets deployed to multiple server. With multi-module you have to define a parent? Which I don't quite under stand why you want to be locked down in that reverse fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So we are setting up maven to download all dependency from a private repository, which works great. But I still want to be able to work on the dependency that it is downloading.

Whether you're using `eclipse:eclipse` or m2eclipse, you can configure projects to use "workspace resolution" (resolve dependencies from the workspace) or binary dependencies. In other words, it just supports your scenario.

Comment: Looking for ide agnostic solution. But yes this would definitely work correctly under eclipse.

Comment: @user461897 Well, *you* mentioned Eclipse :) I'm pretty sure NetBeans and IDEA can do something similar though.